# Calendar Sync with Google Calendar Problem: Deleted Calendar Event still Exist

Tags: iphone, google-calendar

I'm setting up my iphone so that all the mail, calendar and contacts are synchronizing with my Google service, according to [the description here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740).

I find that mail and contacts are synchronizing all right; all the added, edited and deleted emails and contacts are appearing and disappearing as expected, both on the mobile and on Google side.

The problem lie with the calendar. Although the events that I add to Google Calendar does appear in iphone Calendar, but the events that I delete from Google Calendar don't get deleted in iphone calendar.

Anything I do wrong?

Note: What puzzles me is not the device unable to synch with Google Calendar, but rather the synchronization is not complete; it works for the adding of new events, but not the deleting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make sure that the calendar is setup through: http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=139206

Also, make sure you setup as an exchange server and not a Gmail account.

Comment: I tried that but the result is still the same; all the events that I added on Google Calendar are copied to iPhone calendar, but all the events that I deleted from Google Calendar are *not* deleted from iPhone calendar.